# Combine normals of two lines

Tags: math, geometry

i have two lines:
 AB and BC

I can calculate normals of the lines at specific distance - D1 and D2.

I need to calculate x,y coordinates of point D

[image].

I think i can calculate it by rotating point D2 around point B.

[image]

But i don't know how.

Comment: Do the three line segments BD1, BD2 and BD have the same length? From the second figure, they do - I just want to be sure

Comment: Yes, they are at the same distance from the lines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to rotate the vector -- you can get away with adding and normalising vectors.

Add the vectors from B to D1 and from B to D2, normalise the resulting vector to the given length and add its components to the coordinates of B -- this will give you the coordinates of D.

To normalise a vector to a given length, divide its components by its length and multiply with the desired length.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the normals. Take vectors AB and CB, normalize them, add them, scale the resultant vector, then add it to B.

Comment: +1, but be careful with the case that B lies on the line from A to C.